# How to achieve `losetup -a` behaviour with busybox?

Tags: busybox, loop-device

`busybox` (at least version 1.7, which I'm bound to use) to not provide the `losetup -a` switch to obtain a list of currently used loop devices plus the associated filename. Is there any way to obtain such a list with `busybox`?

Comment: `busybox losetup` without additional parameters lists them for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832350/howto-find-the-file-for-a-loopmounted-device:

---

From [losetup(8)](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/losetup8.html) man page

> If only the loopdev argument is given, the status of the corresponding
>   loop device is shown.

So you only need to use

```
$ losetup /dev/loop1
/dev/loop1: [0802]:4751362 (/volumes/jfs.dsk)
```

If you have a recent kernel (2.6.37 or above), you can also get the target file in `/sys/block/loopX/loop/backing_file`.

```
$ cat /sys/block/loop1/loop/backing_file
/volumes/jfs.dsk
```

...

---

Substitite `busybox losetup` for `losetup` above.

Comment: and see `grep -oE 'loop[0-9]+$' /proc/partitions` for the list of loop devices in use (that's what `losetup -a` does).

Comment: I feel kind of stupid for not having tried this... Also thanks @StephaneChazelas, I didn't know `/proc/partitions`